# Laravel + jwt token

Tags: laravel, jwt

Is it possible?

1. jwt is generated with 20mins expiration time
2. for each request middleware checks jwt expiration time and if its lower than lets say 2 min it adds new token in response - old token of course is still valid for next 2mins
3. when frontend received response with new token it starts using it in next requests (if there was some ongoing requests meantime they use old token which is still valid)

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Your question is too large for the stackoverflow. You can use JWT package or laravel passport for your application and change expiration time for JWT token in your .env. However, other items should be coded by you. Your frontend should check the JWT and act accordingly.

Comment: In other word, I would like to generate a new token from an old token. Both the old one and the new one must be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jwt package: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

And In The AuthController ,

You can modifiy the expires_in property just like this:

```
  protected function respondWithToken($token):JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json([
        'message'=>'Successful',
        'access_token' => $token,
        'token_type' => 'bearer',
        'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
        'name' => auth()->user()->name,
        'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'email' => auth()->user()->email,
    ],'200');
}
```

Comment: How to update expiration time without refresh token?

Comment: @GoldenDev I am late to the party, but check the configuration in ```config/jwt.php``` and look for ```JWT_TTL```.